# Google Map Time from Postcode to Postcode

Tags: php, google-maps, echo, bing-maps, bing

I am looking into producing a php script which will calculate the estimated time from one variable to another in the application. The distance will then be printed to the user on screen using an echo statement. So variable postcodeA to variable postcodeB will produce estimatedTimeA .

Which is better to use Bing Maps or Google Maps? I simply require the above functionality no more. Also any ideas on how to start this?

Comment: What is the estimated time based on - the distance?

Comment: Hi Pekka, the speed would be based on the distance.